# How to remove strange characters in the output of a text file with C#?

Tags: c#

I am displaying a text file using this code in C#

```
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(path));
    LabelContent.Text = text.ToString();
```

Once the text is displayed I am getting this (see below -�- ) characthers:

```
    For fine-grained control over your PC�s power settings, click the
    �Change plan settings� link next to the power plan you�ve...
```

My question is how can I get rid of that using C# ?

I'll appreciate any help. Thank you !

Comment: I have tried using ....  text.ToString(), but I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: Well yes you would, its still text - its just characters that font chooses to show as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex.Replace()` with the pattern:

```
"[^\\w\\s\\p{P}\\p{Sm}<>]+"
```

This matches anything that is not a letter, number, punctuation, white space characters, mathematical operators, or tag characters (`"<>"`)  Any character that does not match the pattern, replace it with `String.Empty`.  **If there ends up being other characters you want to keep, then you have to add it to the pattern**.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string fileContent = "    For fine-grained control over your PC�s power settings, click the\n" +
            "<p>    �Change plan settings� link next to the power plan you�ve... </p>";

        fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, "[^\\w\\s\\p{P}\\p{Sm}<>]+", String.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
    For fine-grained control over your PCs power settings, click the
<p>    Change plan settings link next to the power plan youve... </p>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/goYTGG)

Comment: Thank you ! There is only one problem using your code. I forgot to mention, that I am using some HTML tags inside the text file. And by using your code these HTML tags : <p> or <img.../> or even some <div>  will be ignored.

Comment: @TomasJimenez You want the tags removed too?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself well. English is not my native language. I want to keep those tags.  I have noticed that every time I type quots or dashes I get this � instead. If I type &quots; for (") or &ndash for (-), I could get around that, but that's too much work. That's why I thought it must be a way to get rid of these character (programmatically).

Comment: The reason why I want to keep those HTML tags, is because I am applying CSS to all of them.

Comment: @TomasJimenez See updated answer.  As stated in the answer, if there are other characters that you want to keep then add it to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is the matter of properly encoding the UTF characters in the html (I assume you are using ASP.NET) I would try to make sure you encode as utf-8 `<meta charset="utf-8" />`  if this does not work search for other encoding.

Comment: Yes, I am using ASP.NET, and yes I have added already <meta charset="utf-8" />  and I'm still getting the same output (�...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found out how to get rid of those annoying characters (���).
All I have to do is save my text file with the Encoding UTF-8 instead of ANSI, which is the default selection in Notepad.  I have to say that adding alone  won't fix the problem. I had to go back to Notepad and save again my files, but this time using a different Encoder (UTF-8).

However I appreciate all of you, for taking the time to help me.  This site is so great because of all of you.  THANK YOU !!!!